"xlDistinctCount" values not working in python script
While I am using xlDistinctCount value "11" in python script to get distinct count in my Excel Pivot, instead of distinct count I'm getting sum of that particular columns in pivot. Vba values for distinct count. Could you help me how to get distinct values.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlconsolidationfunction
I try to get distinct value in excel's pivot using python but I'm getting sum when i use xlDistinctCount's value 11.
